# How to add to a user_meta field (append)

Tags: user-meta, plugin-gravity-forms

Is this possible? I want to use Gravity Forms or another hook to somehow write to the END of a user_meta field - not overwrite it.

For example...

Before:

```
$purchase_history = get_the_author_meta('purchase_history', $user->ID);
echo $purchase_history; ('Concert in the Park 01/12/2004')
```

After:

```
echo $purchase_history; ('Concert in the Park 01/12/2004', 'Pancake Breakfast 05/15/2005')
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_user_meta()`:

```
$original = get_user_meta( 
    $user->ID, 
    'purchase_history', 
    TRUE 
);

echo $original . ' Pancake Breakfast 05/15/2005';
```

To update the value use `update_user_meta()`:

```
update_user_meta( 
    $user->ID,  
    'purchase_history',   
    $original . 'Pancake Breakfast 05/15/2005' 
);
```

Comment: thanks. i realized this concept after i asked, but now just need to research how to get gravity forms to let me hook into it. have any ideas on that?

Comment: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_pre_submission -- There we go